# Field That Records Former Profile?

Tags: custom-object, process-builder, user, history-tracking

I'm trying to create a Field on the User Object that will record the users former profile.

We're creating a Process Builder that will change the users Profile if the user is set to inactive but we want to keep track of the users original profile for keeps sake and/or if we need to revert back. And if the user's profile changes again, back to the Original Profile then we'd like to Something like this:

```
Original Profile
Inactive Profile
Original Profile
```

I'm not sure how to do this because the Profile will be changing and we don't simply want a field that mirrors the current profile, instead we want one that tracks the profile history.

Any ideas? & thank you in advance.

**Edit** Also what Custom Field do I need to add to the User object itself so that this data populates there? Related lists aren't an option on the User Object. Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPi5R.png)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a child object, much like the way Opportunity stage history tracking is handled. This would be an additional custom object; you could call it "User Profile History". On that new custom object, create a lookup to the User ("User"/`User__c`, a Lookup Relationship) and a text field for the name of the Profile ("Profile Name"/`Profile_Name__c`, Text field, length 255).

Then, in your Process Builder (which fires on changes to your User record), use an immediate action to Create Records. You'll configure it to create a new User Profile History record each time the profile changes. In the section where you populate field values, you would set the `User__c` field to the User's Id, populate the old profile name in the `Profile_Name__c` field, and allow the Created Date of the record to serve as your time-stamp. For both `User__c` and `Profile_Name__c`, the type of data you're populating will be a Reference, since you're pulling it from the User record that started the process.

Comment: Hi David, can you clarify on this please? I got lost in the translation.

-Create Child Object (In the User field?) User Field>Custom Field>New>Hierarchy?

Comment: @Mr.Smith I've expanded my answer.

Comment: Hi David, sorry I'm still struggling with this. Please see edited photos above.

Comment: I generally recommend against placing one-to-many history information in a single field. Instead, I would run a report on Users with User Profile History. If you must, you could use a Long Text Field and design your process to concatenate the existing value in that field with the changed profile name.

Comment: I'm totally lost & what I have so far, if activated, causes an error when saving the user after editing.

Comment: I'd actually be okay by tracking it through a report the way that the Audit train tracks, that's almost perfect. I just don't think that I have the custom object set up properly because I can't get it to generate anything in a report.

Comment: OK, so where are we at at this point? Do you have a working Process that inserts User Profile History records and need to build a report, or is the Process not working? If the Process is not working, what happens and what error do you get?